# React router not working in URL bar, but it still works with <Link> tags

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So I have a route like in the documentation: `<Route path="*"><Redirect to={'/'}/></Route>`.
To make sure that all routes lead to '/' if the route doesnt exists.

All my routes work with a `<Link>` tag but not when I type them in the URL bar.

How can this be? I cant find information about this online.

index file:

```
    return(
  <Fragment>
    <BrowserRouter basename={`/`}>
    <Switch>
        <App>
            <TransitionGroup>
                {routes.map(({ path, Component }) => (
                    <Route key={path} exact path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}${path}`}>
                        {({ match }) => (
                            <CSSTransition in={match != null} timeout={100} classNames={anim} unmountOnExit>
                                <div><Component/></div>
                            </CSSTransition>
                        )}
                    </Route>
                ))}

                <Route exact path="*"><Redirect to={'/'}/></Route>

            </TransitionGroup>
        </App>
    </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Fragment>
  )
```

Route file:

```
export const routes = [
    {
            path:`/`,
            Component:Home
    },
    {
            path:`/login`,
            Component:Login
    },
    {
            path:`/signup`,
            Component:Signup
    },
    {
            path:`/event/:name`,
            Component:Event
    },
    {
            path:`/create-event`,
            Component:CreateEvent
    },
```

]

Link tag:

```
<Link to={"/event/" + events[i].name} className="text-dark">
```

Comment: Please share your routes file code for better understanding.

Comment: Share how you use `<Link>`. Did you add parameter `exact={true}`? Share more code! We aint wizards - we dont know what u have going on there, we cant mind read :<

Comment: Thanks, I added the code. I also found out this doesnt apply to the recursive path. But instead to all the routes.

Comment: Are you running your app in production or development? Is the issue only in production or both in dev/prod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the react-router documentation,

All children of a `<Switch>` should be `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` elements. Only the first child to match the current location will be rendered.

I can see `<Route>` is not a direct or first child to `<Switch>`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Switch` from `react-router` to renders the first child  that matches the location. And be sure to keep, all the known routes before `*` to avoid `redirection` to the `/` path. Following is an example, for your case.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={() => <div>{"MAIN"}</div>} />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/event/:name"
            component={() => <div>{"SELECTED EVENT"}</div>}
          />
          <Route exact path="*" component={() => <Redirect to={"/"} />} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Hope this would solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I added my code now. I also found out this doesnt apply to the recursive path. But instead to all the routes.

Comment: Since you already have the same config as I've given, didn't it work ?

Comment: No unfortunately, I already had this when I asked the question